# LUIS Call Limit

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-ai

Microsoft has added the ability to run Azure AI services on LUIS. Will limits (like 10k calls per month) be applicable for the LUIS container service as well or is it that there would be no limits with containers running ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit as I am using S0 plan for Luis and there is no limit pay as you go.

find the description below for container billing.

The LUIS container sends billing information to Azure, using a Language Understanding resource on your Azure account.

Queries to the container are billed at the pricing tier of the Azure resource used for the .

Cognitive Services containers are not licensed to run without being connected to Azure for metering. Customers need enable the containers to communicate billing information with the metering service at all times. Cognitive Services containers do not send customer data (e.g., the image or text that is being analyzed) to Microsoft. The container reports usage about every 10 to 15 minutes.
for more information check the  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-container-howto#billing)